# CSS background only extending when either border or padding is applied

Tags: html, css

```css
h1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.warning {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}

.warning h2 {
    margin: 100px 0;
}

p {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<h1>LA Fitness</h1>
  <div class='warning'>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    Warning
  </div>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
```

In the above example there is a big space between, "This is a heading", and, "LA Fitness", with the background from `.warning` (black) not appearing in the background.

But if I add either a border or some padding to, `.warning` the background extends underneath. Why is this happening only when a border or padding is added to, `.warning`?

```css
h1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.warning {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
    padding: 1px;
}

.warning h2 {
    margin: 100px 0;
}

p {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<h1>LA Fitness</h1>
<div class='warning'>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    Warning
</div>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` is an "outer margin": It is outside not only the content area, but also outside of the area that is filled by the background.  `padding` however is *inside*  the background area, kind of an "inner margin".

I added `padding-top: 100px` to `.warning` in your example, which demonstrates what I wrote above. The remaining white area above it is the bottom margin of the `h1` above it.

Google for "box model" to get further explanations on this...

```css
h1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.warning {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.warning h2 {
    margin: 100px 0;
}
p {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<h1>LA Fitness</h1>
<div class='warning'>
  <h2>This is a heading</h2>
  Warning
  </div>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's called "margin collapse." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about h2 tag in the warning div:

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
```

It has a 100px margin top. If it parent has padding the margin counts from after of the padding of parent(the second sample). In another way the padding of parent surround margin of children.

But if the parent has no padding margin goes out of its parent and make a 100px distance to previous element.